# How to get second last record from table using subquery

Tags: postgresql, query

I have more then 1000 rows want to get records using subquery, Remember not using offset or limit.

Comment: You'll have to explain why OFFSET is not to be used.

Comment: What do you mean by "last"? Tables have no implicit ordering.

Comment: What does your table and data look like? See [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as the "second last" row in a table. Rows in a relational database have no implied sort order. To identify the "second last", you will have to use an `order by` to define that sort order. If you have a column that can be used for that, you can achieve this using window functions:

```
select *
from (
   select *, 
          row_number() over (order by the_sort_column desc) as rn
   from the_table
) x
where rn = 2;
```

If you have multiple rows that qualify as "second last" (e.g. because you sort by a value that may have duplicates) and you want to see all of them, you probably want to use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`